# Using HTTPBuilder to execute a HTTP DELETE request

Tags: http, groovy

I'm trying to use the Groovy [HTTPBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki) library to delete some data from Firebase via a HTTP DELETE request. If I use `curl`, the following works

```
curl -X DELETE https://my.firebase.io/users/bob.json?auth=my-secret
```

Using the `RESTClient` class from HTTPBuilder works if I use it like this:

```
def client = new RESTClient('https://my.firebase.io/users/bob.json?auth=my-secret')
def response = client.delete(requestContentType: ContentType.ANY)
```

However, when I tried breaking down the URL into it's constituent parts, it doesn't work

```
def client = new RESTClient('https://my.firebase.io')

def response = client.delete(
    requestContentType: ContentType.ANY,
    path: '/users/bob.json',
    query: [auth: 'my-secret']
)
```

I also tried using the `HTTPBuilder` class instead of `RESTClient`

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://my.firebase.io')

// perform a POST request, expecting TEXT response
http.request(Method.DELETE, ContentType.ANY) {
    uri.path = '/users/bob.json'
    uri.query = [auth: 'my-secret']

    // response handler for a success response code
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
    }
}
```

But this also didn't work. Surely there's a more elegant approach than stuffing everything into a single string?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of using `HttpURLClient` [in the tests](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/test/groovy/groovyx/net/http/HttpURLClientTest.groovy) to do a delete, which in its simplest form looks like:

```
def http = new HttpURLClient(url:'https://some/path/')
resp = http.request(method:DELETE, contentType:JSON, path: "destroy/somewhere.json")
def json = resp.data
assert json.id != null
assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
```

Your example is very close to the [test for the delete in a HTTPBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/test/groovy/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilderTest.groovy).

A few differences I see are:

1. Your path is absolute and not relative
2. Your http url path doesn't end with trailing slash
3. You're using content type ANY where test uses JSON. Does the target need the content type to be correct? (Probably not as you're not setting it in curl example unless it's doing some voodoo on your behalf)

Alternatively you could use [apache's HttpDelete](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpDelete.html) but requires more boiler plate. For a HTTP connection this is some code I've got that works. You'll have to fix it for HTTPS though.

```
def createClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams()
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8")
    params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true)

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry()
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80))

    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(registry)
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 8000)
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5400000)
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params)

    return client
}

HttpClient client = createClient()
def url  = new URL("http", host, Integer.parseInt(port), "/dyn/admin/nucleus$component/")
HttpDelete delete = new HttpDelete(url.toURI())
// if you have any basic auth, you can plug it in here
def auth="USER:PASS"
delete.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ${auth.getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()}")

// convert a data map to NVPs
def data = [:]
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(data.size())
data.each { name, value ->
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value))
}

delete.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps))

HttpResponse response = client.execute(delete)
def status = response.statusLine.statusCode
def content = response.entity.content
```

I adopted the code above from a POST version, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Replace the last line with `def content = response.entity.content.text` if you want it as a String.